# switch footer in multi language site

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, wpml

I have a multilingual site and I have used WPML for this purpose. How can I use two different footers when changing the language? The footers are not designed with widgets and are separate pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPML has it's own language code variable, `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE`...  so what you have to do is check that variable for the language you're looking for/want to work with.

WordPress allows you to have multiple footers, you can start by duplicating the theme's `footer.php` file and appending something to the name, like `footer-english.php` then make the necessary changes in that file.

Then you run a conditional check on the WPML language variable, and if it's a match (`==`) to a language code, then you get the footer you want using `get_footer();`.

```
if( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' ):
    get_footer( 'english' ); //will get file footer-english.php
elseif( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr' ):
    get_footer( 'french' );  //will get file footer-french.php
endif;
```

The other way to go about achieving a similar result would be to take the single `footer.php` file and using the `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` variable and conditional `if` checks and just outputting different content within the file based on the language.  I'd only recommend this approach if you have pre-set number of languages and know that you won't be adding any others in the future. You could do something like this:

```
if( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ):
    echo '<div class"site-info">English Site Name</div>';
elseif( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr' ):
    echo '<div class"site-info">Nom de site francais</div>';
endif;
```

I don't believe that'd be as efficient as just running the conditional check once and loading the appropriate footer.php file, but it's always nice to have options.